# What to use instead of window.location.href in chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Hi I am trying to create a chrome extenstion,For making my app to extenstion I am following this steps,

1.Go to chrome option -> More tools -> Extension.

2.I selected the developer mode in that window.

3.I selected the unpacked extention then selected my app.

4.I clicked Pack extension.

In my application I have few html pages,CSS,JS and manifest file and background.js.

**manifest file**

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "........",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "icons": {
        "16": "sample.png"  
    },
    "permissions": [
    "storage","tabs","<all_urls>","webview"
    ],
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('login.html', {
    id: 'main',
    bounds: { width: 1024, height: 768 }
  });
});
```

While Including permissions for tab I am getting th e following warning,

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'tabs' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.
```

My app is not considered as a extension.And I am trying this for page navigation.
I usually use `window.location.href="sample.html"` in jquery. For this I am getting a error in my chrome extension,

```
Use blank _target
```

Then I tried using this line of codes,

```
function clickHandler(e){
  chrome.tabs.update({url:"service1.html"});
  window.close();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click',clickHandler);
});
```

This snippent of code is also not working.Can some one please help me to make my app a extension and help me in page navigation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `location.replace()` function

Comment: Still I am getting this  error. Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://hnbkidfmkmjfoafmcmficmejfcfdjghc/service1.html"; try target="_blank". @claudios

Comment: first remove **app** from manifest, so that chrome doesn't treat it as app (app wrapper, leave background...). Then you *tabs* permission will work

Comment: I could not set bound for this tab. But now this acts as an extension. Can you please help me? @WolfWar

Comment: @Anu *bounds* are only for chromium packaged app windows. You don't use *bounds* for tabs or windows opened from extension. Open tabs with *chrome.tabs* APi or windows with *chrome.windows* API. You also don't need *webview* permission

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to take a look at [Offical Guide for extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), the following is a basic sample based on your requirements, when browser launches (your extension is also executed), it will open `login.html`, there is a login button, once clicking it, `sample.html` will open.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "description": "........",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "sample.png"  
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "login.html"});
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click-me">Click me</button>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("click-me").addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location.href = "sample.html";    
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: login.js is not invoked @Haibara Ai