# Can't redirect through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a chrome extension for a personal project. I made a simple login system with JS and HTML, and logging in works fine when I open the .html in chrome, but it does not want to work when I log in through the google chrome extension. The extension blinks for a split second and does nothing. I find it odd how it works when I open the .html in chrome but not when I try to do it through the extension.

Why does this happen? I've been stuck with this for a good while..

HTML:

```
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="Enter username" style="width: 400px; height: 50px; border: none;"> 

<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="Enter password" style="width: 400px; height: 50px; border: none;">
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

JS:

```
    function validateForm() {
    var un = document.loginform.usr.value;
    var pw = document.loginform.pword.value;
    var username = "a"; 
    var password = "a";
    if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
        window.location = "dashboard.html"
        return false;
    }
    else {
        window.location = "back.html";
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _it does not want to work_? Does it throw an error? Does it crash? What happens?

Comment: @MatheusAvellar Nothing happens. It blinks for a split second and that's about it.

Comment: Could it possibly be an issue with `window.location`? I haven't messed with extensions that much so I'm unsure if that works on an extension

Comment: I assumed it was, and it probably is. I do not know what to use other than window.location, however.

Comment: Perhaps `window.location.href` (from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37046824/4824627))

Comment: I have tried that (sorry for not explaining it very well. I'm stressed as heck), and it did not work. I have been trying most stuff, but none of them work.

Comment: Are you calling `validateForm` anywhere? It isn't shown on the code you provided

Comment: <form name="loginform" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post"> is put above the HTML part I pasted.